# How to load external url and save it on server with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load bing images pages "http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=home+design&qft=+filterui:imagesize-large&safe=off" , and save this url as html with javascript.

here is my code sample that I try :

```
function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  link.click();
}
```

but this code is send file to download on browser.

whether this may be done save url on server with javascript?

Suggestion and corrections are welcome.

Comment: JavaScript is a client-side language. You shouldn't download something using user's browser, and then upload it to server.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev   can you give me example code ?

Comment: @FajarFariyanto He's saying that your strategy is likely wrong. Why don't you give us more details on what result you want to acchieve?

Comment: @Pablo I want to get data from bing search, without having to overload the server.

Comment: You will not be able to do it because of the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: @Pablo if i'm use Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: @FajarFariyanto No, you got it backwards. Bing would have to say they allow you to access their website by using the header. For more details, refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with iframes, although it might not always be available for every site. But Bing seems to be ok with using iframes. I just tried adding the specific URL you listed into an iframe with the following HTML code and it worked:

```
<iframe src="http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=home+design&qft=+filterui:imagesize-large&safe=off"></iframe>
```

For other sites, such as Google, it might not be so easy. Google doesn't allow anything to be loaded in iframes by default, however it seems they will allow specific searches to be configured in your google account and display in iframes on sites you specify.

To achieve with Javascript (since the question mentions javascript) you can just leave the "src" attribute blank and set it using the script, for example if you only have one iframe on the page

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src="http://www.bing.com/";
```

Comment: can store iframe output maybe as cookie on browser?

Comment: Why would you need it to be saved? With iframes each client will perform their own bing search so your server doesn't have to do anything.
Anything saved as a cookie will be sent to your server by the clients so using cookies would be very wasteful.

Comment: because on other page i'll parse this with php, i'm can parse it from cookies